# Opening gnome-terminal and running a command that uses environmental variables from .bashrc

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, environment-variables, bashrc

I am making a .sh file that would be run by Right click -> Run as program by non-power-users. It should open a terminal window and run a `docker run` command, that uses some environmental variables.

My issue is, I am not able to tell the terminal to load these environmental variables.

I have `export VARIABLE=value` in `.bashrc` and tried running

`gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c "source .bashrc && echo \$VARIABLE && echo $VARIABLE"`

but it outputs two empty lines. Interestingly, if I run

`gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -c "cat .bashrc"`

it shows the content of the intended `.bashrc` with `VARIABLE` in it. How can I solve this? I also tried `--rcfile ~/.bashrc`, no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that `bash -c` opens a *non-interactive* shell, and (at least in the case of the default Ubuntu ~/.bashrc, as copied from /etc/skel on account creation), there is this close to the top:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

So unless you added and exported your `VARIABLE` *before* that, it will simply be skipped. You could do either

```
gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -ic "source ~/.bashrc && echo \"\$VARIABLE\"; read"
```

or (simplifying the quoting)

```
gnome-terminal -- /bin/bash -ic 'source ~/.bashrc && echo "$VARIABLE"; read'
```

(I added the `read` to prevent the terminal from exiting with the shell, since my gnome-terminal profile does that by default).

Comment: Meanwhile I have also figured this out, thank you, this is the explanation of what's happening! I ended up adding `-i` after fixing the quotation issues, and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Programs started from the graphical environment don't see variables in `.bashrc`. Create `[some file name].sh` in `/etc/profile.d` instead and set those variables there.

Comment: Do you suggest copying the variables to a separate file in `/etc/profile.d`? Other thing: it seems like they don't even see environmental variables even if they are set, e.g. `gnome-terminal -- bash -c "export VARIABLE=value; echo $VARIABLE;"` doesn't print anything. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I just realised I should use `'` instead of `"` or use `\$` inside `"` to be taken literally, so please ignore the second sentence.

Comment: @Rolf: Yes, that's my suggestion. Maybe worth a try.